# how to organise a multivolume book series in (La)TeX

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, thesis

When searching the questions asked on this list I came accross 
"*Starting a PhD; Any guides to setting up a 'system'?*"
but the problem for me is that a **multivolume book series** 
(not necessarily written at the same time but can be over a period of time, 
first part I and a few year later the second part that interlinks with the first part and so on)

I thought of the following but neither one is satisfactionary for me because of the comments:

## partial solution one:

```
 \part{Volume I}
 \input{VolI} %here comes book 1: elementary topics of
 \part{Volume II}
 \input{VolII} %here comes book 2: basic topics of
 \part{Volume III}
 \input{VolIII} %here comes book 3: advanced topics of
```

write the multivolume book as one book where the multivolumes are put in the parts and the bibliography is a bib file from bibTeX that adds the references if used and discard the rest (which will be from another part)

### positive:

all volumes are connected to each other with commands/label/refs/...

### negative:

I have to have an index/table of content for part I and then later part II (which will also include the index/table of content from volume I again...or may miss many parts that link to it if the other volumes are commented out) If there is a bibliographic reference in volume I and II for the same book then I have to use the same key again and I cann't generate a partial bibliography for each chapter seperately.

## partial solution two:

write each one volume book as a book and make some export files that can be imported when started on volume 2 for example and so on.

### positive:

will probably work but is a lot of work because everything from 
table of content/index/bibliography commands need to be rewritten to include 
the volume number

### negative:

a lot of work to get everything organised and a lot of files!!

The problem becomes more problematic when after first editions are being made
for volume I, volume II and volume III for example a second edition comes 
from volume I for example. Maybe then a intermediate file has to be made to 
keep track of what the new references are instead of the ones mentioned.

Is there a simpler complete solution to my problem?? I would like to change 
LaTeX to include a volume number with the table of content/index/bibliography that can be included at will.

Comment: Have you given a look to `memoir` class? It has a `\book` sectioning command for that purpose.